# Tab index not working on submit button in html?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I created the design like this.But submit Tabindex not working .Please check this and let me know.

```
 <input id="id" type="text" value=""  class="input" tabindex="1"/>
  <input id="userName" type="text" value=""   tabindex="2"/>
 <input  type="button" value="search" onclick="searchbyrole()"  tabindex="3"/>
```

After entering the username when click on enter not firing search action.Please tell me why tabindex not executing properly.

Comment: It seems to be working to me - I changed the index just to be sure: http://jsfiddle.net/9bhsn/  Do you really need to use `tabindex`?  If your fields all sit in your markup in the order you want them to be used you're better off omitting them entirely.

Comment: The code does not reproduce the problem. Please provide a minimal document that actually demonstrates the problem. Also specify the browser(s) tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) { // return
            $('#IdOfTheButton').trigger('click');
        }
    });
</script>
```